# Slide back to top

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I am using WP mystickymenu. You can see it running here: http://wordpress.transformnews.com/plugins/mystickymenu-simple-sticky-fixed-on-top-menu-implementation-for-twentythirteen-menu-269

So, when you scroll down, it comes from the top with a menu and stays there until you scroll back to the top. The main problem I have is that it goes hidden so quickly when you go back to the top and I want it to go back in the same way it shows, I mean *slide* up.

When it comes, it uses the slide down effect, and I am looking to make it go back also with a slide top effect instead of going back hidden quickly.

Here is the JS:

```
    //disable at small screen sizes
var myfixed_disable_small = parseInt(mysticky_name.mysticky_disable_at_width_string);
var mybodyWidth = parseInt(document.body.clientWidth);

if (mybodyWidth >= myfixed_disable_small) {
// select mysticky class
var mysticky_navbar = document.querySelector(mysticky_name.mysticky_string);

// add mysticky_wrap div around selected mysticky class
var parentmysticky = mysticky_navbar.parentNode;
var wrappermysticky = document.createElement('div');
var position = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < parentmysticky.childNodes.length; i++) {
if(parentmysticky.childNodes[i] == mysticky_navbar) {
position = i;
break;
};
};
wrappermysticky.id = 'mysticky-wrap';
wrappermysticky.appendChild(mysticky_navbar);
parentmysticky.insertBefore(wrappermysticky, parentmysticky.childNodes[position]);

// add mysticky_nav div inside selected mysticky class
var parentnav = mysticky_navbar.parentNode;
var wrappernav = document.createElement('div');
wrappernav.id = 'mysticky-nav';
parentnav.replaceChild(wrappernav, mysticky_navbar);
wrappernav.appendChild(mysticky_navbar);

// add myfixed and wrapfixed class to divs while scroll
var mysticky_active_on_height = parseInt(mysticky_name.mysticky_active_on_height_string) ;
var origOffsetY = mysticky_active_on_height ;
var mydivHeight = ((mysticky_navbar.offsetHeight) + 'px');

var hasScrollY = 'scrollY' in window;
function onScroll(e) {
var mydivWidth = ((mysticky_navbar.offsetWidth) + 'px');
var mydivReset = '';

var y = hasScrollY ? window.scrollY : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
y >= origOffsetY  ? mysticky_navbar.classList.add('myfixed') : mysticky_navbar.classList.remove('myfixed');
y >= origOffsetY  ? wrappernav.classList.add('wrapfixed') : wrappernav.classList.remove('wrapfixed');
y >= origOffsetY  ? mysticky_navbar.style.width = mydivWidth : mysticky_navbar.style.width = mydivReset;
y >= origOffsetY  ? wrappermysticky.style.height = mydivHeight : wrappermysticky.style.height = mydivReset;
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
};
```

Does anyone know how to make it to go back hidden in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a easing when the menu is revealed.  But when you scroll up, it just disappears. You need to find the effect that controls the disappearance.

Look in .js files for the effect that controls "mysticky-nav" which is the id of the sticky menu itself. It appears to be an "animate" effect when it comes down.  You'll want to edit the effect when it disappears.

Assuming this is a plugin, check the plugin folder for .js files as they might not be shown in the source of the page itself.

Hope this helps!